# Block Particular Command in Linux for Specific Users

Tags: linux, security, account-restrictions, restricted-shell

I want to whitelist some of the commands for users. I am getting solution using LShell [Limited Shell](https://github.com/ghantoos/lshell) but I want to restrict subcommands as well.

I want user to access `docker ps` and `docker logs` only. How can I achieve it via LShell?

Comment: What is an LShell?

Comment: May this help you ? https://access.redhat.com/solutions/65822

Comment: @ramius that doesn't use `lshell ` though

Comment: `lshell` is more efficient that rbash. That's why, I looking for solutions in lshell.

Comment: I don't know much about `lshell`, but looking at the documentation it seems not possible to restrict access to subcommands. Do you think it may be possible to use a wrapper script for the `docker` executable ?

Comment: I have found a solution, that allows to alias the commands such as `docker-ps='docker ps'` But I am looking for a solution that allow `docker ps` instead of alias.

Comment: users of your shell also aren't allowed to pass any command line options or environment variables and write files anywhere, right, @mhassaankhokhar? Because otherwise they can just write a docker config file, use it with `--config /path/to/their/config.json` or by exporting `DOCKER_CONFIG=/path/to/their/config.json` and do whatever they want in it (e.g. by adding any program as credHelper and thus gaining unrestrained access)

Comment: I just did one thing. I created a bash script that only allows `docker ps` and `docker logs` to the user. Then I copied that file into `/usr/bin/docker_custom`. Next I made `alias` like `{'docker':'docker_custom'}` and gave the permission to user `docker`. It is working fine for me. In this way, my user is only allowed to run `ps` and `logs` only.